# How to create calculated column to assign a row tag to the Max Operation Sequence within a range of a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
| Manufacturing   Router Template ID | Operation Sequence | Gate | Calculated Column   |
|------------------------------------|--------------------|------|---------------------|
| XXX1                               | 10                 | A    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 20                 | A    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 30                 | A    | Last Gate Operation |
| XXX1                               | 40                 | B    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 50                 | B    | Last Gate Operation |
| XXX1                               | 60                 | C    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 70                 | C    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 80                 | C    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 90                 | C    |                     |
| XXX1                               | 100                | C    | Last Gate Operation |
| XXX2                               | 10                 | A    |                     |
| XXX2                               | 20                 | A    | Last Gate Operation |
| XXX2                               | 30                 | B    |                     |
| XXX2                               | 40                 | B    |                     |
| XXX2                               | 50                 | B    |                     |
| XXX2                               | 60                 | B    | Last Gate Operation |
| XXX2                               | 70                 | C    |                     |
| XXX2                               | 80                 | C    | Last Gate Operation |
```

Sample data shows 2 Router Template examples XXX1 and XXX2 that have a different number of operation sequences within it (XXX1 has 10 operations numbered 10-100 while XXX2 has 8 operations numbered 10-80). On top of that, the operations are assigned Gates (A, B, C). The calculated column shows the result i'm trying to generate: which is to have a formula that can assign the max operation sequence within each Gate (A, B, C) within each router template (XXX1, XXX2) a row tag 'Latest Gate Operation'

A formula i've tried using is a IF - MAX - INDEX function, kind of like this:

```
=IF(MAX(INDEX((A2=$A$2:$A$15000) * (B2=$B$2:$B$15000) * (C2=$C$2:$C$15000),)),"Lastest Gate Operation","")
```

Which is most definitely incorrect. Any help would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Are these first three columns *always* in order?

Comment: Yes the data is always provided in order.

Comment: Then please add in `D2`: `=IF(C3<>C2,"Last Gate Operation","")` and drag down. See if that's what you are after and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: In case the data is not sorted, then you can use COUNTIFS, `=IF(COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$19;C2;$A$2:$A$19;A2;$B$2:$B$19;">"&B2)=0;"Last Gate Operation";"")` This will work even with data not sorted.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, thanks @JvdV, it worked great!